# Replacing a fragment with another fragment shows both fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

Inside a fragment class I want to replace the current fragment with another fragment when the user clicks on a button:

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttoncambiarfoto:
                fragment = new AboutFragment();
                replaceFragment(fragment);
                break;

            case R.id.buttoncambiarusername:
                fragment = new AboutFragment();
                replaceFragment(fragment);
                break;
        }
    }
    public void replaceFragment(Fragment someFragment) {

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.perfilId, someFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

It works, but the current fragment remains on screen, and the new fragment appears at the same time.

What am I doing wrong?

EDITED, current fragment layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/perfilId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.juarezserver.mergeapp.fragment.PerfilFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/fotoPerfil"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person_pin_black_24dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttoncambiarfoto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/btn_logut_bg"
                android:text="Editar Foto del Perfil" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:text="Datos Personales"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/bg_register"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:text="Nombre de usuario"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="italic" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Modesto" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttoncambiarusername"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/btn_logut_bg"
                    android:text="Cambiar nombre de usuario" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Nombre"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="italic" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtNombre"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Modesto" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button7"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/btn_logut_bg"
                    android:text="Cambiar nombre" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Apellidos"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="italic" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtApellidos"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Modesto" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/btn_logut_bg"
                    android:text="Cambiar apellidos" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Email"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="italic" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Modesto" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Celular"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="italic" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtCel"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Modesto" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button6"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/btn_logut_bg"
                    android:text="Cambiar celular" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: you added the same fragment? what's the problem

Comment: `fragment = new AboutFragment();`...you are adding the same fragment double times..check

Comment: add background to root layout of fragment

Comment: @LinhNguyen, the problem is that current fragment remains on screen when the new fragment is shown

Comment: @rafsanahmad007, I know, that is not the issue

Comment: @mvasco this problem occured with me also.. I've done a workground I'm posting it

Comment: Did you mean, when you press back it return to AboutFragment again ?

Comment: set background for LinearLayout after scrollview...

Comment: The first argument in the `replace()` call is the ID for the `ViewGroup` that will hold the `Fragment`, not for a `ViewGroup` in the `Fragment`s layout. You're sticking the second `Fragment` inside the first one. Also note that `Fragment`s declared in `<fragment>` elements in your layout cannot be removed/replaced dynamically.

Comment: @mvasco problem is with your layout..... `FrameLayout` should be a container do not declare elements inside it.. just replace a layout inside it with the first layout you want... then your fragment replce will work

Comment: @AbhishekSingh, what do you mean with: replace a layout inside it with the first layout you want?

Comment: @mvasco is it your container layout or not? I thought its a container layout

Answer (score 0):

remove :         `transaction.addToBackStack(null);`
dont add the same fragment in to a backstack

Comment: Thank you, but your proposal doesn´t solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This code will remove the problem of current fragment remains on screen, and the new fragment appears at the same time. also will help you to manage backstack. I'm using this on `BottomNavigationView`, also you can use with `NavigationView`. I don't know It can be reduced or not but works great for me

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.nav_home:
            mFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Fragment_Home");
            if(!(mFragment!=null && mFragment.isVisible())){
                mFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate("Fragment_Home", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment(), "Fragment_Home").addToBackStack("Fragment_Home").commit();
            }else if(mFragment!=null && !mFragment.isVisible()){
                mFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate("Fragment_Home", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, mFragment, "Fragment_Home").addToBackStack("Fragment_Home").commit();
            }
            return true;
        case R.id.nav_account:
            mFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Fragment_Account");
            if(!(mFragment != null && mFragment.isVisible())){
                mFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate("Fragment_Account", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new AccountFragment(), "Fragment_Account").addToBackStack("Fragment_Account").commit();
            }else if(mFragment!=null && !mFragment.isVisible()){
                mFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate("Fragment_Account", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, mFragment, "Fragment_Account").addToBackStack("Fragment_Account").commit();
            }
            return true;
        case R.id.nav_category:
            mFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Fragment_Category");
            if(!(mFragment != null && mFragment.isVisible())){
                mFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate("Fragment_Category", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new CategoryFragment(), "Fragment_Category").addToBackStack("Fragment_Category").commit();
            }else if(mFragment!=null && !mFragment.isVisible()){
                mFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate("Fragment_Category", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, mFragment, "Fragment_Category").addToBackStack("Fragment_Category").commit();
            }
            return true;
        case R.id.nav_services:
            mFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Fragment_Services");
            if(!(mFragment != null && mFragment.isVisible())){
                mFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate("Fragment_Services", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new ServicesFragment(), "Fragment_Services").addToBackStack("Fragment_Services").commit();
            }else if(mFragment!=null && !mFragment.isVisible()){
                mFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate("Fragment_Services", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, mFragment, "Fragment_Services").addToBackStack("Fragment_Services").commit();
            }
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Tag with Fragment and try it...

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment someFragment, String fragmentTag) {

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.perfilId, someFragment, fragmentTag);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

And add fragment Tag like below:-

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttoncambiarfoto:
            fragment = new AboutFragment();
            replaceFragment(fragment,"CAMBIAR_FOTO_FRAGMENT");
            break;

        case R.id.buttoncambiarusername:
            fragment = new AboutFragment();
            replaceFragment(fragment,"CAMBIAR_USERNAME_FRAGMENT");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: and what should I change inside public void onClick(View view), to call replaceFragment with both parameters?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override       
public void onClick(View view) {
Fragment fragment = null;
switch (view.getId()) {
case R.id.buttoncambiarfoto:                 
fragment = new "Change the fragment class constructor here with respect to the button click"
                    replaceFragment(fragment);
                    break;
                case R.id.buttoncambiarusername:
                    fragment = new "Change the fragment class constructor here with respect to the button click "

                    replaceFragment(fragment);

                    break;

            }

        }

        public void replaceFragment(Fragment someFragment) {


            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            transaction.replace(R.id.perfilId, someFragment);

            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            transaction.commit();

        }
```

Comment: Thank you, but same result.

Comment: you can also check the onCreateView  of the respective fragment and check whether you have initialized corresponding xml layout for it and not the same xml file for both the class.

Comment: @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.class_layout_xml, container, false);
    }

Comment: check this out.